# MySQL cumulative fiscal year with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (MySQL) with column: Year, Month, zone, warehouse, amount (my data not duplicate).

I want to use the query cumulative of 'Amount' via fiscal year group by zone and warehouse. (start the month of the fiscal year is April).
For Example:

```
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| year| month |zone | warehouse| amount |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   4   |  A  |    WH    |  2400  |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   4   |  B  |    WH    |  1200  |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   4   |  A  |    BW    |  200   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   5   |  B  |    WH    |  300   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   5   |  C  |    CW    |  300   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   6   |  A  |    WH    |  450   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   7   |  B  |    WH    |  200   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   7   |  C  |    CW    |  100   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2018|   9   |  A  |    WH    |  1000  |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   1   |  B  |    WH    |  200   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   1   |  C  |    CW    |  100   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   3   |  A  |    BW    |  100   |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   4   |  A  |    WH    |  20    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   4   |  B  |    WH    |  10    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   5   |  C  |    CW    |  70    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019|   5   |  B  |    WH    |  20    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+
```

And I want to select data from DB to include cumulative:
Year, Month, Zone, warehouse, amount, Cumulative

```
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| year| month |zone | warehouse| amount | Cumulative |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   4   |  A  |    WH    |  2400  |    2400    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   4   |  B  |    WH    |  1200  |    1200    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   4   |  A  |    BW    |  200   |    200     |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   5   |  B  |    WH    |  300   |    1500    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   5   |  C  |    CW    |  300   |    300     |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   6   |  A  |    WH    |  450   |    2850    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   7   |  B  |    WH    |  200   |    1700    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   7   |  C  |    CW    |  100   |    400     |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2018|   9   |  A  |    WH    |  1000  |    3850    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   1   |  B  |    WH    |  200   |    1900    |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   1   |  C  |    CW    |  100   |    500     |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   3   |  A  |    BW    |  100   |    300     |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   4   |  A  |    WH    |  20    |    20      |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   4   |  B  |    WH    |  10    |    10      |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   5   |  C  |    CW    |  70    |    70      |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
| 2019|   5   |  B  |    WH    |  20    |    30      |
+-----+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+
```

What query can help me do this?

Comment: Not an uncommon question try searching for mysql cumulative total

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and don't forget to include the primary key

Comment: I tried searching before asking questions but the results did not produce what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery for that purpose:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT coalesce(sum(temp.amount), 0)
        FROM your_table temp
        WHERE temp.year = your_table.year
          AND temp.month < your_table.month
          AND temp.zone = your_table.zone
          AND temp.warehouse = your_table.warehouse
       ) + amount AS cumulative
FROM your_table;
```

**You can check the demo here: [db< >fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f716caec2bebc8a9158777a14e7e5664)**

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: thank you. Your query help me. Now i learn more 'coalesce', :).

Comment: @LongNguyễn You're welcome. I'm glad that it helped you. And `coalesce()` returns a first non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL now supports window functions.  This is the best way to solve the problem:

```
SELECT *,
      SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY zone, warehouse, year ORDER BY month) as cumulative
FROM t;
```

Not only is this simpler to express than a subquery, but it should have much better performance.